# Rotating a line into negative coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a line, using the following function:

```
def rotate_line(line, theta):
    angle_cos = numpy.cos(theta)
    angle_sin = numpy.sin(theta)
    ox, oy = line[0]
    
    for i in range(len(line)):
        px, py = line[i]
        qx = ox + angle_cos * (px - ox) - angle_sin  * (py - oy)
        qy = oy + angle_sin  * (px - ox) + angle_cos * (py - oy)
        
        line[i] = numpy.array([qx, qy])
    
    return line
```

But I get this result (red - original, orange - rotation), instead of the expected one:

[image]

I've tried a variety of other functions, yet all of them give me the same incorrect results. Why?

Test code:

```
line = numpy.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]])
print(line)
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(1, 1, color = 'green')
ax.plot(line[:, 0].tolist(), line[:, 1].tolist(), color = 'red')
line = rotate_line(line, numpy.deg2rad(90))
print(line)
ax.plot(line[:, 0].tolist(), line[:, 1].tolist(), color = 'orange')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you modify the original `line` in your `rotate_line` function. You need to introduce a new variable (e.g. `new_line`) to record the coordinates of the orthogonal line. You can do it for instance like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rotate_line(line, theta):
    angle_cos = np.cos(theta)
    angle_sin = np.sin(theta)
    ox, oy = line[0]

    new_line = np.zeros((line.shape[0], line.shape[1]))
    for i in range(len(line)):
        px, py = line[i]
        qx = ox + angle_cos * (px - ox) - angle_sin * (py - oy)
        qy = oy + angle_sin * (px - ox) + angle_cos * (py - oy)

        new_line[i] = np.array([qx, qy])

    return new_line

line = np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]])
print(line)
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(1, 1, color='green')
ax.plot(line[:, 0].tolist(), line[:, 1].tolist(), color='red')
line = rotate_line(line, np.deg2rad(90))
print(line)
ax.plot(line[:, 0].tolist(), line[:, 1].tolist(), color='orange')
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Rotated line]